# how to get the complete time when I run a sql script using monetdb

Tags: sql, monetdb

when I use the command-line interface of sql after I type "mclient -dmydatabase", if I type the "select...." instruction directly, I will get the complete time like this

(query result)

7 tuples (15.4s)

but if I put the same instruction into the sql script like default_22.sql, after I run the script I will only get the answer without the time like this:

(query result)

7 tuples

so I hope to know that how can I get the complete time when I run the script using the monetdb? thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the -i flag e.g.

mclient -dmydatabase -i scriptfile

Comment: thank you for answering, but when I type the command like this:

Comment: thank you for answering, but when I type the command like this:"mclient -dnewdb -i /path/to/sql/script/default_1.sql",I also can not get the complete time automatically, can I set a parameter in monetdb to achieve this goal?or I can only add sql commands to achieve this?

Comment: thank you,your method is right,and my machine have installed an old version that I don't realize before,so in that context your method doesn't work.after I change a machine your method works.